# NiceScroll disables mousewheel on edges of page

Tags: scroll, overflow, nicescroll

I'm using the NiceScroll library and having some trouble that is specific to Google Chrome.

When the cursor is over the left and right edges of the page, the mouse wheel does not allow the page to scroll.

If I change the HTML "overflow" tag from "hidden" to "visible", two scroll bars are visible (NiceScroll + Native). Under this regime, the mouse wheel again functions on the edges of the page. However, it is the native "jumpy" scrolling.

This suggests that NiceScroll is ceding control of scrolling at some boundary. How can I change this boundary?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your all content in `<div></div>`. The issue is this "gaps" http://s7.postimg.org/gubbxv0gr/nise_Scroll.png

By some reasons this area is ignored by NiceScroll and avoid correct call to scroll api. So if you will have a wrapper (like on a screen body > div) then it should work.